# Is the geometrical term ''sector'' strictly used only for circles?

Tags: geometry, terminology

If you draw numerous straight lines from the centre of a circle to the circumference the resulting (pizza slice shaped) parts are called sectors.

But what about the triangular parts you get if you divide, say, a regular polygon? If you draw $8$ straight lines from the centre of an octagon to the vertices, can those triangular parts be called sectors of the octagon?

If not, then what is the technical term for those divided parts of a polygon?

Comment: And also, do the radial lines have to pass through just the vertices of the polygon, or is any point on the perimeter OK?

Comment: @timtfj For now I'd just like to know the case where they pass through the vertices.

Comment: For the record, "sector" is also used with ellipses, hyperbolas, parabolas, and spheres. A simple web search shows that "polygonal sector" was used by Euclid himself; eg, Proposition XIV of Book 4 of *Elements*. ([Here's a Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=5INRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA294&lpg=PA294&dq=polygonal+sector), which may not work for everyone.) In any case, polygonal-izing curvy objects isn't uncommon; there are "polygonal paths" and "polygonal arcs", so your audience should be okay with "polygonal sector" (and probably even just "sector" when context is clear).

Comment: @Blue Here's a navigable version but unfortunately the numbering seems to be different. Hopefully the right proposition is nearby though? https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIV/propIV14.html

Comment: @Blue But I think "Euclid used phrase $P$" is risky without looking at the original Greek or the translator's notes. It might turn out to be a word which doesn't have a direct English equivalent, but is traditionally translated as $P$ in editions of Euclid to express his meaning of it.  (That would still be an argument for its usability, though.)